# bash script for loop, add html tag on each output

Tags: html, bash, loops, for-loop, tags

To add html tags like td /td etc (basically building a table from the output) I'm using sed in my for loop:

```
for host in `cat hostlist`;do echo "$host " | sed 's|\(.*\)|<tr><td>\1</td>|'; cat $host | grep "CPU util" | grep " [5-9][0-9]%" | sed 's|\(.*\)|<td>\1</td></tr>|'; done
```

Output no sed:

```
switch1

switch2
Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%
Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%
CPU utilization for five seconds: 63%; one minute: 23%;  five minutes: 18%
switch3
CPU utilization for five seconds: 78%/0%; one minute: 43%; five minutes: 40%
```

Output with sed:

```
<tr><td>switch1 </td>
<tr><td>switch2 </td>
<td>Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%</td></tr>
<td>Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%</td></tr>
<td>CPU utilization for five seconds: 63%; one minute: 23%;  five minutes: 18%</td></tr>
<tr><td>switch3 </td>
<td>CPU utilization for five seconds: 78%/0%; one minute: 43%; five minutes: 40%</td></tr>
```

This doesn't add the tags to empty lines like the one below switch1 (when grep returns 0) and also for switch 2 I want all the outut in one table cell like this:

Desired Output:

```
<tr><td>switch1 </td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr><td>switch2 </td>
<td>Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%<brZ
Core 0: CPU utilization for five seconds: 56%; one minute: 11%; five minutes: 8%<br>
CPU utilization for five seconds: 63%; one minute: 23%;  five minutes: 18%</td></tr>
<tr><td>switch3 </td>
<td>CPU utilization for five seconds: 78%/0%; one minute: 43%; five minutes: 40%</td></tr>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Use awk, something like this `awk '/CPU util/{print "<td>" $0 "</td>"} !/CPU util/ {print "<tr><td>" $0 "</td>"}'`. You'll find the right answer in a couple seconds and even fewer lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/CPU util/{
    print "<td>" $0 "</tr>"
} 
!/CPU util/ {
    if ($1 == "")
        print "<tr><td>" $0 "</tr>"
    else 
        print "<tr><td>" $0 "</td>"
}' file_name`
```

Will do the trick for you. Since I tested it and it seems to work, I decided to answer rather than comment.